# Scala/ Java, Summing up two arrays columns in a Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following Dataset, currently using the UDF to sum up the arrays.
The performance is slow since I'm using an UDF.

Instead I'm looking to use High order functions or spark.sql.functions or any other effective way to sum up the array.

```
Id  Country State    Vector_1                   Vector_2
1     US     IL   [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]   [5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0]

1     US     IL   [5.0,3.0,3.0,2.0,1.0]   [5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0]

2     US     TX   [6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,1.0]   [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
```

The output should looks like this

```
Id  Country State    Vector_1                      Vector_2
1     US     IL   [6.0,5.0,6.0,6.0,6.0]    [10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0] 
2     US     TX    [6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,1.0]    [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregating arrays element wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46857449/aggregating-arrays-element-wise)